# How to write services with $q and $http calls without being repetitive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service

I'm trying to figure out an elegant way to write AngularJS services without being so repetitive with the $q syntax.

Currently, I'm writing services like follows:

```
(function() {

    function ServiceFactory($q, $timeout, $http) {
        return {
            getFoo: function() {
                var deferred = $q.defer();

                $timeout(function() {
                    $http.get('/the/foo/thing').then(function(response) {
                        if (response.isError) {
                            deferred.reject();
                        } else {
                            deferred.resolve(response.data.foo);
                        }
                    }, function() {
                        deferred.reject();
                    });
                });

                return deferred.promise;
            }
        };
    }

    angular.module('myapp').service('MyService', ['$q', '$timeout', '$http', ServiceFactory]);

}.call(this));
```

It works very well, buy I'm always writing down a bunch of code just to delay $http.get and expose a Promise. Sometimes I will have some extra stuff into success callback, like handling data, creating a different response object... But most of the time, is just like the code above: `call $q.defer + $http.get().then... + return promise`

So, I'm thinking about a way to clean up/reduce the code without affecting the clarity of what I'm doing, e.g if another developer open the file, it should not be a mystery.

As a side note, the $http service here is actually a decorator, handling server responses to give me a more structured object with things like `response.isError` and `response.data`.

Also, I have seen a similar solution in another question {1}, but this is not as same. Just returning the response of `$http.get().then()` will expose the entire response to controllers on response, and it is not the desired effect. Instead, when I call `MyService.getFoo().then(...)`, I'm expecting a `foo` object as a response from service, fed by server via `response.data.foo`, or a call to `errorCallback`.

I've forgot to mention: my server is not RESTful, so `$resource` is not an option right now. My URLs are more like `/thing/get/:id`, `/thing/do-stuff/:id`.

[{1} Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17913956/abstracting-http-calls-into-service)

Comment: I've forgot to mention that my server is not RESTful, so $resource is not an option right now. My URLs are more like `/thing/get/:id`, `/thing/remove/:id`.

Comment: Not really a problem, I'm using resources with query string params right now. You can do much customizations to match your server.

Comment: Can you just throw the url into the function arguments, so you can reuse all your code for all of your get requests to each url?

Comment: Not really, Zack. As I mentioned, sometimes I need to extract some data from response object. I'm trying to figure out a way to reduce the code without compromise the readability. I'll try the $resource service as gustavohenke mentioned. Maybe it is the elegant solution I'm looking for. I'll play around with it and update the question with my discoveries. Thanks for the help, anyway.

Comment: Definitely go with resources, doesn't matter if your server is RESTful. Use the `transformResponse` option of action definitions, if you want to customize the returned object. Absolutely use `.$resolved`. We have a similar use case (not RESTful server side) and saw the code beign reduced to 50% - sometimes 30%.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thinking for a while, I figured out a better way to write the services. I've done some changes to `$http` response, and now my implementation is returning a Promise whenever a Controller calls `http.get()` or whatever http methods. With this implementation, I've reduced the methods' code to two or three lines per request in most of the cases. Now I should try to use the AngularJS decorator setup.

A working example is here:

http://embed.plnkr.co/p4EHQAbE40XWXjBWqjIM/preview